# Using Jupyter Notebook with pyspark error no import named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark, package

As explained, I'm using pyspark in jupyter notebook.  I'm getting the attached errors.

I have a tf-idf; I normalize it; then this last step creates a cosine-similarity matrix for documents.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix

mat = IndexedRowMatrix(
data.select("V2", "norm")\
    .rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(row.ID, row.norm.toArray()))).toBlockMatrix()
```

But this is the error I'm getting: at the bottom it says "no module named numpy"

```
2022-08-25 15:16:26,161 WARN scheduler.DAGScheduler: Broadcasting large task binary with size 4.0 MiB
2022-08-25 15:16:27,561 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 15)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 601, in main
func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in read_command
command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 160, in _read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 430, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:713)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:695)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
```

Oddly, numpy is installed correctly.  So that's the issue:  numpy is installed correctly but pyspark isn't able to find it while creating a cosine-similarity matrix in a jupyte notebook.

Thank you for considering this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Jupyter Notebook as an application within AWS EMR, try using a bootstrap script which installs the required version of numpy while provisioning the cluster

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Of note, though I'm running pyspark, right now I'm only running it locally on my laptop, so it's a standalone "cluster" .  Once I'm able to get this step running, I'll be able to go from 60 to 17000 documents, and I'll have to figure out how to get the same code running on my remote spark cluster.  But for now, the error "no module named numpy" seems to indicate that numpy isn't installed locally, where the standalone cluster is running.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe there are multiple python installations. The python version you use in jupyter might not have numpy installed on it. Try checking that out